# How can I modify the MAPPING constant in ActiveSupport::Timezone in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add a new timezone to our timezone dropdown. I want to add the Mapping "Atlantic Standard Time" => "America/Puerto Rico" for usability purposes.

I believe I can modify the hash ActiveSupport::Timezone.MAPPING by doing something like

```
ActiveSupport::Timezone.MAPPING["Atlantic Standard Time"] = "America/Puerto_Rico"
```

Would this work and would it be best put into an initializer or somewhere else?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just handle this in your application code instead of mucking with the framework?

Comment: Would be best not to do it. Someone else may inherit that code in the future and have a very bad day.

Comment: i prefer to copy the hash and add yours timezone, put it as const or helper function for your view